# PHP IMAP and gmail get mailbox display name

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I am connecting to gmail using PHP and imap using the code below. I can then fetch list of emails 1 week old. I am looking for a way to be able to get the display name of the mailbox account from gmail instead of having to put it in the code. Is this possible?

```
$stream = @imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $username, $password);

if ($stream) { 

    $emails = imap_search($stream, 'SINCE '. date('d-M-Y',strtotime("-1 week")));

} else {

    echo "<p>Gmail Error: ".imap_last_error()."</p>";

}
```

Comment: i cannot seem to find anywhere where this is possible. Is there a way to maybe get information of the latest received message and take the recipient name from that as my display name?